# Phoniebox.de - No audio issues due to snd_usb_audio file missing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, raspbian-stretch

RPi Model 3 B+

Used this to install the stretch

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2018-03-14/2018-03-13-raspbian-stretch.zip

as recommended on here

https://github.com/MiczFlor/RPi-Jukebox-RFID/wiki/INSTALL-stretch

installed the one liner script (tried them all)

Installing is fine, everything seems to work BUT...

from this here:

https://github.com/MiczFlor/RPi-Jukebox-RFID/wiki/Troubleshooting-FAQ#audio-is-not-working

If that doesn't work, check if the device is recognised by your Pi:

$ cat /proc/asound/modules
0 snd_bcm2835
1 snd_usb_audio
This shows that device 1 is the usb audio card. Open the sound configuration file.

I am missing the snd_usb_audio

Can someone please tell me exactly why this is missing and if there is anyway I can get the file to be put on there (with you telling me exactly everything I need to do).

Is the SD card corrupt?

Is the RPi 3 Model B+ corrupt?

Thank you.

By the way I don't have an external sound card, just the RPi 3 Model B+ and will use a USB powered speaker only

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Does your system report a USB sound card which you don't have?

Comment: I have no idea. I haven't brought a sound card for it. Just going to use the in built sound for it via mono speakers. When installing the phoniebox I don't have the speakers plugged into one of the USB sockets.